# Newb question: How to maintain a data list for all users in my webapp?

Tags: javascript, vercel, sveltekit

Disclaimer: I'm finding my way and not sure how to ask the question. This is what I want to do:

I am getting data from twitter API in my app (this is working).

I then want to store that data (as an array), and serve it to whichever user is accessing the app (so that I don't need to query the API everytime, just poll every 10 mins).

What do I need to be able to do this? (external database? or can I just save to a file on the server in someway? or something else)

For ref I'm building with sveltekit, and deploying with vercel.

Comment: You can just store it in the memory, through a global variable?

Comment: how would it be available to any user accessing the app @NoraSöderlund?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Twitter's API directly within your own app, every user of your app needs to query the API at least once to get some data. You cannot serve the results that are returned to one user to other users without having your own back-end server and handling this accordingly. However, you can save a copy of the data returned to each user to that user's [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) so that specific user does not have to query the API every time.

You can save the data on the client's localStorage and save an expiry timestamp that allows you to query the API again after the timestamp has passed.

[Here](https://rodneylab.com/using-local-storage-sveltekit/) is a tutorial on how to use localStorage with SvelteKit

Comment: I guess I'm then looking for the simplest way to have my own backend server

Comment: That is a very unfocused question. A simple Google search would yield lots of tips.